# How can I enforce function to have return declarations in Typescript 1.5 on VS2015?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

I am using Typescript 1.5 and Visual Studio 2015. Is there a way for me to force typescript to do checking to ensure that all of my functions have return types declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your projectfile to use "TypeScriptNoImplicitAny" then you need to declare the type of your variables or you will get the TS7006 TypeScript Parameter error.

To to that open you projectfile and under:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
```

Add:

```
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>true</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
```